# How to resolve "Segmentation fault: 11" error when running nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am using Mac OS Yosemite. I use `npm install -g n` to install the `n` module to try to upgrade nodejs. Then
I run

```
n stable
```

But I received an error during the upgrade and it quit unexpectedly.

Then when I type "node -v" I get an error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

In fact I get this error when I type `npm install` and `node` so literally I can't use node or npm anymore.

What does it mean? how can I get my node.js back? I tried to reinstall it using 
`brew install node` but after the install I still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your node modules folder and try to reinstall. Depending on what version of node you were previously running your modules could need to rebuild for compatibility

Comment: Thanks I just removed everything related to node in the `/usr/local` directory and reinstalled Node successfully.

Comment: Worked for me too where node started giving seg faults. Remove the modules folder and `run npm` install again.